# React: 502 Bad Gateway on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a webapp frontend using AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Since NodeJS uses 3000 I changed the PORT environment variable of the beanstalk env to 3000.

The problem:
The deployment is shown successful in AWS console but when I try to access the webpage I get 502 bad gateway. I sifted through the logs and it seems the node is stuck/looping at `Starting the development server...`  stage.

The web.stdout.log file has the following printed over and over:

```
Jul  5 20:34:41 ip- web: > webapp@0.1.0 start /var/app/current
Jul  5 20:34:41 ip- web: > react-scripts start
Jul  5 20:34:45 ip- web: #033[34mℹ#033[39m #033[90m｢wds｣#033[39m: Project is running at http://xx.xx.xx/
Jul  5 20:34:45 ip- web: #033[34mℹ#033[39m #033[90m｢wds｣#033[39m: webpack output is served from
Jul  5 20:34:45 ip- web: #033[34mℹ#033[39m #033[90m｢wds｣#033[39m: Content not from webpack is served from /var/app/current/public
Jul  5 20:34:45 ip- web: #033[34mℹ#033[39m #033[90m｢wds｣#033[39m: 404s will fallback to /
Jul  5 20:34:45 ip- web: Starting the development server...
```

What I've tried so far:

1. I saw a suggestion that the instance might have ran out of memory so I switched the instance to t3.small but it didn't work. It was still stuck
2. Instead of changing the PORT env variable I changed the default port of Node to 8080 (nginx default port in beanstalk) in package.json. It was still stuck.
   My guess is that load balancer needs to be configured to listen to port 3000. But I don't know how to do that properly.

Can someone please help me with this? I'll provide if any extra information is needed.

Comment: Do you have a specific need to start the development server? You can serve static content on EB without development server I think

Comment: In AWS console, go to EC2, on the left, find Load balancing > Load balancers. Is there a listener ID HTTP : 80?

Comment: Yes. Its there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serving static content using `npm run build` solved my problem.

I think its not possible to run development server on EB.